# How to create a client for Authorization Code Grant with PKCE in Laravel Passport?

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, client, laravel-passport

I'm trying to implement the **Authorization Code Grant with PKCE ** flow in Laravel Passport. [Its documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#creating-a-auth-pkce-grant-client) says that I have to use this command:

```
php artisan passport:client --public
```

That's fine, but I have to do it manually, I want to create those clients automatically, I mean, bring to my users a dashboard where they can create their clients. For that, I need to call through Ajax (or fetch) from my frontend some endpoint of Laravel Passport who allows me to create PKCE clients, but I don't know which endpoint call.

Laravel Passport provides the [`POST /oauth/clients`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#post-oauthclients) endpoint to create clients, but this only create Authorization Code Grant Clients (without PKCE) and I don't know how to specify to create a PKCE client (same problem for Password Grant Tokens clients).

I was searching in the [Laravel Passport's Client Controller](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/10.x/src/Http/Controllers/ClientController.php#L78) and I realized that I can't specify what kind of client I want, this is the `store` method of Laravel Passport's Client Controller:

```php
public function store(Request $request) {

    $this->validation->make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|max:191',
        'redirect' => ['required', $this->redirectRule],
        'confidential' => 'boolean',
    ])->validate();

    $client = $this->clients->create(
        $request->user()->getAuthIdentifier(), $request->name, $request->redirect,
        null, false, false, (bool) $request->input('confidential', true)
    );

    if (Passport::$hashesClientSecrets) {
        return ['plainSecret' => $client->plainSecret] + $client->toArray();
    }

    return $client->makeVisible('secret');
    
}
```

As you can see, in the `create()` method of the client, values are "hard-coded" preventing me to create another kind of client through the JSON API.

Also, I was searching in the [Laravel Passport's Client Model](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/10.x/src/Client.php#L42) and I realized that, with the model I can specify what kind of grants I want for that client:

```php
protected $casts = [
    'grant_types' => 'array',
    'personal_access_client' => 'bool',
    'password_client' => 'bool',
    'revoked' => 'bool',
];
```

So, there have to be a way to create clients for any type of grants (like PKCE), but I don't know how.

Should I override the Laravel Passport's Client Controller? How can I do it? I know that I can use the model to create my own clients in my own endpoint, but I want to keep the `POST /oauth/clients` route, so I would need to override the Laravel Passport's Client Controller, but I don't know how, can you help me, please?